# React router not reload old component when all route path is dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this routes system

```
     ....
    <Route  path="/:slug_1/:slug_2" name="component_2" component={component_2}/>
    <Route  path="/:slug_1" name="component_1" component={component_1}/>
    ....
```

When loading a home page I click on a component_1 link by path `.../slug-1` After I click a component_2 link by path `.../slug-1/slug-2`. But after this when I click a component_1 link and in URL it creates a path `.../slug-2/slug-1` but it must be path `.../slug-1` only

Please help me))

Comment: Do you tried `exact` props on `<Route>`. It will only load component_id when path is set to "/:slug_1" and same for the component_2.

Comment: @SagarGavhane Yes, I tried and do not help

Comment: I think there is a mistake inside `<Link to="path"/>`. Can you show `<Link />` tag to path

Comment: @SagarGavhane links paths make in loop <Link to={slug} />

Comment: @SagarGavhane yeah.